# data to be string in respond: function(status, data, headers, statusText)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have an API call as:

```
  $http.post(that.auth.apiUrl + '/data/auth', authParam).then(function (jsonObj) {

//jsonObj.data is string
                        var data = JSON.parse(jsonObj.data);
    }
```

It returns a JSON object with string in data like
Object {data: "{"userId":1,"userFormat":"2"}", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

For its unit testing, I have a mocked a http request like:

var mockObj = {
                "userid": 1,
                "userFormat" : "2"
            };

As I need data to be string I did stringify

```
 $httpBackend.when('POST', apiUrl + '/data/auth').respond( 200,
                        JSON.stringify(mockObj)
                );
```

but it returns 
Object{data: Object{userid: 1, userFormat: '2'}, status: 200, headers: function (name) { ...

so instead of getting string in data object, I'm getting another Object. How can I make it in string format? I want the data to have a string value instead of an object with userId and format

Comment: Why do you want to have a string there, if I may ask?

Comment: the controller /data/auth returns a stringified  json object

Comment: What happens if you try sending the data by itself without the status? `$httpBackend.when('POST', apiUrl + '/data/auth').respond(JSON.stringify(mockObj));` have you tried?

Comment: I'd say you should fix your real controller, not mock. For me it looks like problem with 'Content-Type' header. You can try to find a way to make $httpBackend respond with 'plain/text' type, but much better would be to fix your real service to return 'application/json' and remove this `JSON.parse(jsonObj.data)`

Comment: We don't know if he/she has the ability or access to change what the server is returning. I think it's fair to answer the question keeping that in mind.

Comment: I cannot change what the server is returning it returns "jsonobject.toString" and I need my test to return : Object {data: "{"userId":1,"userFormat":"2"}", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}                                                                                                              and $httpBackend.when('POST',apiUrl/data/auth').respond(JSON.stringify(mockObj)) returns the same

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend it looks like `respond()` takes a callback function (that returns an array) *or* data. I don't see an option where it takes a status code and then data.

```
var mockObj = { "userid": 1, "userFormat" : "2" };
$httpBackend.when('POST', apiUrl + '/data/auth').respond(JSON.stringify(mockObj));
```

Comment: I get the same response on doing like this too

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I gave mock object a string and again stringify it like

```
var mockObj = "{ 'userid': 1, 'userFormat' : '2' }";
$httpBackend.when('POST', apiUrl + '/data/auth').respond(JSON.stringify(mockObj));
```